# MySQL console runs the query, Python doesn't

Tags: python, mysql

I have thoroughly searched for a solution but couldn't find any.
Issue is that I can run below query successfully in MySQL console while when I try to run it using Python it gives error. I'm able to run other sql queries using python but not this one.

Query -

```
    qry = "UPDATE test.flight_track e, 
           (SELECT c.connection,COUNT(c.bag_seal_number) bag_count 
           FROM 
           (SELECT a.bag_seal_number, a.status_code, a.connection, a.scanned_datetime 
           FROM 
           livedata.livebag a 
           WHERE a.auto_incr IN (SELECT MAX(b.auto_incr) FROM livedata.livebag b 
           GROUP BY b.bag_seal_number)) c 
           WHERE c.status_code = 'In Transit' 
           GROUP BY c.connection) d 
           SET e.bag_count = d.bag_count 
           WHERE e.conn_id = d.connection"

    cursor.execute(qry)
    db.commit()
```

Error-

```
    _mysql_exceptions.OperationalError: (1046, 'No database selected')
```

Comment: Please edit this so the code is readable. To make a code block jump down two spaces and indent over 4 spaces. Paste the code in. As it stands now this hard to read Edit: much nicer formatting now

Comment: Is this your complete python code ? Do you have connection part ?

Comment: I'm sorry for that, it was first time I posted any question. It's readable now.

Comment: Can we see a sample of your connection file? Are you sure that you are connected at the time that this query is being executed?

Comment: it's as follow -
db = MySQLdb.connect("dashboardcentral.cz3sq5x0ps8m.ap-southeast-1.rds.amazonaws.com","bhas*****","***********",local_infile = 1 ); 
cursor=db.cursor().
I'm sure I'm connected because for the same connection I'm able to execute other SQL queries.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your query, try explicitly selecting the database and let us know if that works:

```
USE database_name
```

It doesn't seem to be an issue with the query itself based on the error that you are receiving.

Comment: Thanks ! it worked. Although I'm using two databases in the query but I just added 'USE db' line for one of them (USE test). I don't get this why it happened this way. I had mentioned each db name before each table occurrence.

Comment: @BhaskarChoudhary Glad I was able to help. SQL is weird like that sometimes. I've made it practice to always explicitly name the database I want to use in my queries to avoid this exact situation. Glad it's working now

Comment: I'm gonna do the same from now on and thanks again :)